# Scroll collection view with button action

Tags: ios

I am having a collection view which shows 3 cells as visible. when i click the right arrow button, It should scroll to show the next 3 cells and when i click the left arrow button, It should scroll to show the previous 3 cells. In case if there is 2 cells behind, it should show those 2 cells with previous last visible cell.

can someone help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have found the solution.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     oldrow=0;
}
- (IBAction)right_button:(id)sender
{
     NSIndexPath *newIndexPath;

    if (xr-1>0) {

        oldsection = 0;
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldrow+3 inSection:0];
        oldrow=oldrow+3;
        [collection_vw scrollToItemAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
        xr--;
        xl++;
    }
    else if (y>0)
    {
        [_btn_right setHidden:YES];
        oldsection = 0;
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:array_stories.count-3 inSection:0];
        oldrow=array_stories.count-3;
        [collection_vw scrollToItemAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
    }


}

where
 xr=array_stories.count/3;
 xl=0;
 y=array_stories.count%3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do

```
  [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

where you need to pass indexpath for next item you want to scroll